# How to calculate a correlation between variables which are proportions of observations varying in sample size

Tags: correlation, binomial-distribution, proportion

Is it possible to calculate the correlation between two proportions, while accounting for the individual sample size that is used to calculate the proportion per individual?

For example:
How do I calculate the correlation between the proportion of heads from one coin, and the proportion of heads from another coin, when tossed by the same individual. Not every individual tosses every coin as often (some individuals even toss one of the two coins once).

Is this even possible?

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear: would your dataset then consist of records that look like (individual identifier, # tosses of coin 1, proportion heads in coin 1, # tosses of coin 2, proportion heads in coin 2)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)

Comment: It sounds perfectly possible. It does not sound likely to be interesting or useful.

Comment: How would this be possible then? I actually have a practical problem which I just simplified here (the dataset looks just like whuber described), so it would definitely be useful...

Comment: The proportions could just be the two variables you put into a correlation function, command or routine. But if some data points are 0s and 1s from individual tosses, some means of several tosses, the results would just be a mishmash of data points of quite different reliability.

Comment: You could try weighting by the number of tosses. Naturally, what you are giving as an example, coin tosses, could be a long way from your real problem, so that correlations might make more sense for that real problem -- but we don't know what your real problem is.

Comment: Thanks! How would you weight such a proportion? The coin tosses btw are actually a pretty good representation of the real problem. The real problem involves the proportion of boys or girls among the offspring of an individual :-)

Comment: @Abdel, did you find a solution to your problem?